# Jest testing with React, fireEvent.keyPress is not working

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am new to Jest and trying to test the fireEvent.keyPress while pressing the delete button, As I saw in the documentation the keyPress is expecting the input as the first argument and the option (which key is pressed) as the second, but the problem is I need to test the `Delete` button pressing whenever I press it. The problem is that keyPress button is not getting called if I don't pass the first argument. Any workaround on avoiding passing the first parameter to fireEvent.keyPress ?

Comment: Please show a minimal, reproducible code example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing `document` or `document.body` as the node argument for your key press function.
`fireEvent.keyDown(document.body, { key: 'Escape' );`